# How would i take multiple url's out of a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am having my server send me a list of all the images in a certain users folder, it sends me a string and i am using SBJsonparser to get it. here is the coding:

```
   NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/members/grabimages.php?&username=%@", [getLogin objectAtIndex:0]];

NSString *connect = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];

NSString *imagenames = [[NSString alloc]init];
imagenames = [parser objectWithString:connect error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", imagenames);
```

The string returns this:

```
(
"./username/default/img1.jpg",
"./username/default/img2.jpg"
)
```

There is going to be lots of URL's in this one string at some point, i want to be able to separate all the URL's and then add each one of them into a new string.

How would i be able to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error from the other post error says the object was an `NSMutableArray`. presumably, that object was `imagenames`.

if so, then you declare it like so:

`NSArray *imagenames = [parser objectWithString:connect error:nil];`

then you use your relative base url to compose the url, as they are relative to some directory you must know of. so, you would compose the base (as an `NSURL`), and use one of the `-[NSURL URLByAppending...` methods to create new URLs from the elements of `imagenames`.

Comment: Ahh. made it a mutablearray and it worked completely fine, Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSArray *array = [imagenames componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; to separate the the urls

Comment: -[__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x351610
2011-10-29 21:10:18.062 Pic Cloud[1625:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x351610'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x370f08bf 0x324601e5 0x370f3acb 0x370f2945 0x3704d680 0x7033 0x31d017ff 0x31d0bd53 0x31d0bcc1 0x31dab339 0x31daa14f 0x31e04d97 0x3 etc etc ect